# Cluster Analysis using R for large data sample

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am just starting out with segmenting a customer database using R I have for an ecommerce retail business. I seek some guidance about the best approach to proceed with for this exercise.
I have searched the topics already posted here and tried them out myself like dist() and hclust(). However I am running into one issue or another and not able to overcome it since I am new to using R.
Here is the brief description of my problem.
I have approximately 480K records of customers who have bought so far. The data contains following columns:

- email id
- gender
- city
- total transactions so far
- average basket value
- average basket size ( no of item purchased during one transaction)
- average discount claimed per transaction
- No of days since the user first purchased
- Average duration between two purchases
- No of days since last transaction

The business goal of this exercise is to identify the most profitable segments and encourage repeat purchases in those segments using campaigns. Can I please get some guidance as to how to do this successfully without running into problems like the size of the sample or the data type of columns?

Comment: Do you know how to subset your data so that you get a matrix with only the numerical data? If so, do that and then call `dist` and `hclust`. I imagine that you might have to adjust some of the fields if any of them are prone to large variances. And if this isn't enough info, it might be a good idea to provide a sample of your data and what goes wrong so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply blakeoft. Here is the further information I must provide:

Comment: 1. I'm afraid I don't know how to subset data
2. Yes, some fields like days since last transaction have large variances. Values ranging from 1 to 1400

Comment: Unable to provide the exact data sample. However, I can tell that the columns are exactly the same as the ones described in the question. First 3 columns (email, gender and city) are text, rest are numerics. Here is the error I got on trying dist()
> d<- dist(cust_data, method = "euclidean")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 861.9 Gb
> hc<-hclust(cust_data,"ave")
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: this question has more to do about clustering techniques than programming, and should be asked on Cross Validated, not SO

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm) to learn how to subset data frames. When you try to define d, it looks like you're providing way to much data, which might be fixed by subsetting your table first. If not, you might want to take a random sample of your data instead of all of it. Suppose you know that columns 4 through 10 of your data frame called `cust_data` contain numerical data, then you might try this:

```
cust_data2 <- cust_data[, 4:10]
d <- dist(cust_data2)
```

For large values, you may want to log transform them--just experiment and see what makes sense. I really am not sure about this, and that's just a suggestion. Maybe choosing a more appropriate clustering or distance metric would be better.

Finally, when you run hclust, you need to pass in the d matrix, and not the original data set.

```
h <- hclust(d, "ave")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly your data does not contain any attributes that indicate what types of items/transactions did NOT result in a sale.

I am not sure if clustering is the way to go here.

Here are some ideas:

First split your data into a training set (say 70%) and a test set.

Set up a simple linear regression model with,say, "average basket value" as a response variable, and all other variables as independent variables.

`fit <-lm(averagebasketvalue ~., data = custdata)`

Run the model on the training set, determine significant attributes (those with at least one star in the `summary(fit)` output), then focus on those variables.

Check your regression coefficients on the test set, by calculating R-squared and Sum of squared errors (SSE) on the test set. You can use the predict() function , the calls will look like

```
fitpred <- predict(fit, newdata=testset)
summary(fitpred) # will give you R²
```

Maybe "city" contains too many unique values to be meaningful. Try to generalize them by introducing a new attribute CityClass (e.g. BigCity-MediumCity-SmallCity ... or whatever classification scheme is useful for your cities). You might also condition the model on "gender". Drop "email id".

This can go on for a while... play with the model to try to get better R-squared and SSEs.

I think a tree-based model (rpart)  might also work well here.

Then you might change to cluster analysis at a later time.

Comment: Thank you very much blakeoft and knb, your responses are extremely helpful. Will surely try these and update the progress here, if it is advisable. Again, apologies if the question is misplaced, for the lack of clarity on the approach itself.